# Angular JS not calling JsonResult After Hosting on IIS

Tags: c#, angularjs, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

I am creating a Web App in .NetCore with Angular Js, Its working Fine in testing on localhost . But when I host it in IIS server it failed to call a JsonResult Method

Below is my Code [Angular Js]

```
         $http({
                url: '/Home/GetDetails',
                method: "GET",
                params: {
                    StaffCode: $scope.StaffCode,
                }
            }).then(function mySuccess(response) 
                {
                }, function myError(response) {
                $window.alert('An Error Occurred , Try Again Later');
            });
```

it is working fine on localhost , But after hosting on IIS server call to **GetDetails** Jsonresult is happening in wrong way

For example :

http://10.1.10.10/ApplicationName/Home/Index is the Web address of Application

And Call to **GetDetails** jsonresult is

http://10.1.10.10/Home/GetDetails [Gives Error 404 : File Not Found]

Instead of http://10.1.10.10/ApplicationName/Home/GetDetails

I tried

```
url: '~/Home/GetDetails',
```

And

```
url: './Home/GetDetails',
```

But it does not seems to call right address of Jsonresult Method

What is the correct Format of url here ?

Comment: is this an MVC app? Use the Razor helper methods to build the correct URL based on the controller and action names.

Comment: you should use `Url.Action` instead like : `url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails","Home")'` which will make sure to generate correct relative url

Comment: @ADyson , Yes its an MVC App and its an external JS file , so URl.Action or URLhelper does not work here

Comment: presumably the JS in the external file must be triggered to execute by something in the view? In that case you can simply pass the URL to it as a function parameter, or maybe set global variables or something which can be used by any JS.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad , Angular Code is in External JS File

Comment: @Jack you would need to utlilize the html5 data attribute like : `data-url='@Url.Action("GetDetails","Home")'` and then some how use it when your particular event fires in that inject the url to your function call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you have hard-coded the urls which does not work if application is hosted inside some directory but not in root folder, so the solution is to always use `Url.Action` helper method to generate the correct relative urls like:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails","Home")'
```

This will make sure to generate the correct url regardless of application is hosted how much nested sub-directories.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My Angular Code is in External file , its not in MVC View . Otherwise I would have gone for this solution allready

Comment: @Jack in that case you would need to utlilize the html5 data attribute like : data-url='@Url.Action("GetDetails","Home")' and then some how use it when your particular event fires in that inject the url to your function call